# c++ overload: string literal vs. boost::function ambiguity

Tags: c++, string, function, boost, overloading

my problem code:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

void func (const std::string&) {}
void func (const boost::function<void()>&) {}

int main() {
    func (main); // good
    func ("bad");
    return 0;
}
```

=>

```
error: call of overloaded ‘func(const char [4])’ is ambiguous
overload.cpp:4: note: candidates are: void func(const std::string&)
overload.cpp:5: note:                 void func(const boost::function<void ()()>&)
```

I know I could resolve this by explicitly calling func (string ("bad")); or by providing a func (const char*), but I wonder if there is a way to keep the caller side as in the example and without introducing more overloads.

Maybe something with boost::enable_if?
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: do you really think the cause is the overload which takes `boost::function`, have you for example tried to compile without that overload? Will that work?

Comment: yes its caused by boost::function. The example I posted reproduces the whole situation.

Comment: yeah - didn't test before asking, just slightly bemused that this was the case - looks like it is.. hmm.. short of providing overloads for everything, not sure there is a neat solution for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't easily solve this. `boost::function<>` and `std::function<>` don't support only functors callable by `f()`, but also pointer to members callable by `(secondArg.*firstArg)()` and data members, so their constructors basically slurp everything in, and later decide what to do with the type.

It's not trivial at all to write such a SFINAE testing class that guards from implicit conversions (and I'm not even sure whether it would be at all possible, since the Standard library doesn't do it. That must have some reason). Remember that a type may be callable because of many different properties - it may have a conversion function to function pointer type etc pp. Writing a SFINAE class that could make this work means to reject an implicit conversion in some cases and accept an implicit conversion in other cases based on really not obvious properties at all.

If you want to avoid this ambiguity, I would try just choose a different function name or if it's a one-shot problem, do the casting on the caller side.

Comment: Old question, but for future readers there is a defect report on this for `std::function`. See [2132. std::function ambiguity](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2132) which is currently implemented in g++4.8.

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
void func (const char *s) {  func(string(s)); }
```

update

```
template<class A0, ...>
void func (const A0 &a0, ...) {
    func(argize(a0), ...); // convert chars to strig, otherwise jut pass
}
```

Comment: the problem is, the code will be actually auto generated and there are possibly already a lot of overloads like func (string); func (string, int); func (string, int, boost::function) and so on.  So adding char*-overloads is unfortunately not an option.